# Best way to map local JS to live website for debugging (Fiddler alternative for MAC)

Tags: javascript, macos, mapping, remote-debugging

I came up to an issue when trying to debug a live site by mapping local JS file to the website. On Windows I use Fiddler successfully, but I got no solution for Mac OSX. I tried Chrome workspaces, but it does not really work (when I refresh the browser, the local mapping disappears).

Any ideas?

TA

Comment: Do you mean plugins like [tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/)?

Comment: I need a plugin, extension that enable me to map my local JS to replace the remote JS on a live website (for MAC OSX). I will try this out and let you know if that makes sense. Thank you

Comment: Nope, that does not map local to remote.